# Adding KML layer to google map API 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make it so that when the user selects some things from a form and hits submit it will add all the stuff to the google map. Adding markers works perfectly fine and add a listening event to add polylines works fine also. For some reason the KML file will not overlay correctly. I am not sure I am doing it correctly though. The value from the form does echo out correctly so I know the data is reaching at least to the map function. Here is the code that is not working:

```
window.onload = function() {
        // Creating an object literal containing the properties
        // we want to pass to the map
        var options = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.09, -95.71),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // Creating the map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
        // Creating a LatLngBounds object
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        // Creating an empty MVCArray
        var route = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: route,
            strokeColor: "#ff0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.6,
            strokeWeight: 5
        });      
        polyline.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
            var path = polyline.getPath();
            path.push(e.latLng);
        });
        kmlFiles.setMap(map);
```

here is the code that sets the kmlFiles variable:

```
kmlFiles = new google.maps.KmlLayer(<?php echo $_POST['kmlFile']; ?>);
```

Comment: The code looks ok to me. What goes wrong exactly? Do you actually need to use a kml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are missing quotes around the URL that you are passing to KMLLayer e.g.

var layer =  new google.maps.KmlLayer(http://www.site.com/foo.kml);

is invalid while

var layer =  new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://www.site.com/foo.kml");

is valid.