# Looking for examples of polyline with google maps V 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps, polyline

I am looking for examlpes of how to use polylines in V3 of Google maps, I have read the help at Google but must admit I don't fully understand. I feel if I could see a good example I might understand it better. What I have is a site that I track my vehicle I have it plotting the points on the map what I want is to draw the line between the points. I am using a mysql database and a XML file with PHP to display the point on the map.

Any help would make my day. I have found this site very helpful and I wish to thank all.

Take care, all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of creating a [KML xml file](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html#basic_kml), using data from your database, and [feed google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626717/adding-kml-layer-to-google-map-api-3) with that. You can use [this tool](http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html) to interactively see how the kml file changes while adding points to the polyline.

EDIT:

1. Create a script in your preferred scripting language which retrieves the points from database, and generates a kml file format as in the third link above.
2. In your javascript script, you need to add a kml layer to the map, loading the kml you generate on the fly in your script at point 1. :

   [...]
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
   [...]
   kmlFiles = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://yourdomain.com/generatekml.php");
   kmlFiles.setMap(map);

and that's it.

Comment: First I wish to thank you, but I have a question. I used the tool and made a javascript file that works in my code to place a line on the map but what I need to to take the points I have on the map and link them with a polyline.                                           var myCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(46.038431,-64.927714),
new google.maps.LatLng(46.170781,-64.683269)
];
var polyOptions = {
path: myCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1,
strokeWeight: 3
}
var it = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
it.setMap(map);

Comment: First I wish to thank you, but I have a question. I used the tool and made a javascript file that works in my code to place a line on the map but what I need to to take the points I have on the map and link them with a polyline. The var myCoordinates = [ new google.maps.LatLng(46.101730,-64.773906), new google.maps.LatLng(46.099706,-64.773090), new google.maps.LatLng(46.100093,-64.771288), new google.maps.LatLng(46.101164,-64.769528), new google.maps.LatLng(46.102265,-64.769915) ];

Comment: What I need is the var myCoordinates = [ ]; to be the data from the markers from the XML file I am importing and displaying as icons on the map they are working now. I just want a line between each one I not sure how to place the information in the brackets  "new google.maps.LatLng(46.100093,-64.771288)," Thak=nks for the help you have give me it is a start.

Comment: I am having trouble with the KML file but I have no problem with XML with that also work?

Comment: ok I have the kml working<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
- <Document>
  <coordinates>-64.783,46.0727</coordinates> 
  <coordinates>-64.7892,46.0848</coordinates> 
  <coordinates>-64.7868,46.0882</coordinates> 
  <coordinates>-64.7832,46.0888</coordinates> 
  <coordinates>-64.7828,46.0887</coordinates>

Comment: 64.8547,46.1123</coordinates> </Document> </kml> I added to my javascript the [...] var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options); [...] kmlFiles = new google.maps.KmlLayer("http://My info to file here"); kmlFiles.setMap(map); but the map is blank. Is the output of the KML correct? Thanks

Comment: did you remove the [...] from the code? i just meant *your code* (map initialization / configuration) with those ellipses; then check the console to see which error cause the map to be blank